# Installing Unity3d on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

According to this [blog post](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/08/26/unity-comes-to-linux-experimental-build-now-available/) I should be able to install the .deb version of the Unity Editor for Ubuntu. I have the recommended system requirements. But when I try to install the .deb file using the `sudo dpkg -i mydebfile.deb` I get the following errors:

```
Selecting previously unselected package unity-editor.
(Reading database ... 175283 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack unity-editor-5.3.4f1 20160503_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking unity-editor (5.3.4f1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of unity-editor:
 unity-editor depends on lib32gcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1); however:
  Package lib32gcc1 is not installed.
 unity-editor depends on lib32stdc++6 (>= 4.6); however:
  Package lib32stdc++6 is not installed.
 unity-editor depends on libc6-i386 (>= 2.15); however:
  Package libc6-i386 is not installed.
 unity-editor depends on libpq5; however:
  Package libpq5 is not installed.
 unity-editor depends on npm; however:
  Package npm is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package unity-editor (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160415-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 unity-editor
```

Has anybody successfully installed the Unity3d on Ubuntu 16.04 yet? Please help if you can.

**EDIT:** I've been asked if the question [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line) has solved my problem. The answer is: No, it hasn't. The answers in that question might help one learn how to fix broken dependencies using `sudo apt-get -f install` but that didn't solve my problem. I had to install each of the missing packages one by one (see comments below). So, I think people coming here for the same problem won't be able to know that they have to install the packages by hand if the question is marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line)

Comment: It's specific to Unity so, not quite a dupe, but I see your point! The answers on this thread are now out of date (no more .deb file), see [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1082653/504866) for instructions.

Comment: Why is this question being flagged over and over again as a duplicate question? Please read the last paragraph of the question before reviewing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dpkg -i` command does not resolve dependencies and pull them from *apt* repositories. You need to install the package using the *Ubuntu Software* application, or you will need to `apt-get install` the listed dependencies by hand in a terminal, so that they will be installed and the dependencies for the `unity-editor.deb` file satisfied.

Comment: I believe that running `sudo apt-get install -f` after installing a DEB will install the dependencies for it.

Comment: @dobey installing each one of the dependencies by hand sorted out the problem.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I concur with you.

Comment: @dobey Why not pasting here command which installs all Unity3D dependencies? I think that it might be useful for others?

Answer (score 6):

### Download

> Unity is providing official support for Ubuntu

You can always get the latest releases of `Unity3D`:

- [Unity on Linux: Release Notes and Known Issues](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/)

*scroll down the page for the latest release.*

---

### Install

- [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/a/841370/538619)

Comment: New way of installing Unity. Same link. No file .deb anymore. You'll get an installation assistant file with extension .0b1 this time. Make it executable 'chmod +x name.0b1'  and run it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `gdebi`! install this gdebi on Ubuntu software, and open file manaager, go to Download, and open terminal on Download. and run:

1.`gdebi [.deb file you downloaded.deb(full name)]` 
and wait...

2. type `y` when you see `[y/n]`.
3. try to open Unity editor!

But there is one error I found: If you login, it always shows 'Service not available, please try again later.'
Don't try to wait. it ALWAYS shows me.

Answer (score 0):

The answers on this page are now all slightly out of date. Unity are no longer providing a `.deb` file. It took me a minute, but go to this thread:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/

And navigate to the last page. Click on the link in the very last post (as instructed) and download the executable. After downloading you will need to add execution rights, either do this via the GUI (right click, go to permissions, and check "Allow executing file as program") or from your command line simply run

`chmod +x unity-setup-filename`

Now you can open the new graphical assisted installer!

Answer (score 0):

To summarize [this post](https://www.paperstartgames.com/install-unity3d-in-ubuntu-18_04/)

> #### INSTALL UNITY3D IN UBUNTU 18.04
>
> Find the latest Unity3D on Linux from [HERE](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/page-2)
>
> ```
> sudo apt install -y libgconf-*
> wget https://beta.unity3d.com/download/<checksum>/UnitySetup-YYYY.X.ZZZ
> chmod +x UnitySetup-YYYY.X.ZZZ
> ./UnitySetup-YYYY.X.ZZZ
> ln -s Unity3D-YYYY.X.ZZZ/Editor/Unity /usr/bin/unity3d
> ```