# Unity 3d installation error

Tags: dpkg, unity3d

I am using Ubuntu 17.04 and I am trying to install unity 3d on it but  after finishing the process it's not in Applicatons. I search for it but I can't find it.

I also tried with GDEBI Package Installer but it show error `Dependency is not satisfiable: libpng 12-0`

```
$ sudo dpkg -i Downloads/FlareGet/Applications/unity-editor-5.1.0f3+2015082501_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package unity-editor.
(Reading database ... 175908 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../unity-editor-5.1.0f3+2015082501_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking unity-editor (5.1.0f3) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of unity-editor:
 unity-editor depends on lib32gcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1); however:
  Package lib32gcc1 is not installed.
 unity-editor depends on lib32stdc++6 (>= 4.6); however:
  Package lib32stdc++6 is not installed.
 unity-editor depends on libc6-i386 (>= 2.15); however:
  Package libc6-i386 is not installed.
 unity-editor depends on libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.22.0); however:
  Package libpango1.0-0 is not installed.
 unity-editor depends on libpng12-0; however:
  Package libpng12-0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package unity-editor (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+17.04.20170406-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 unity-editor

$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  unity-editor
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 2,991 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 182828 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing unity-editor (5.1.0f3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+17.04.20170406-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-9ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-1) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok first: The reason why it didn't appear in the applications is that it hasn't been installed ... see the line of your output where it says

"The following packages will be **REMOVED:**
  unity-editor "

As explained in [Installing Unity3d on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774401/installing-unity3d-on-ubuntu-16-04) `dpkg` does not handle dependencies. If possible try `gdebi` or some dpendecie resolving installer.

If `apt-get install -f` does not work maybe try a newer version of Unity?

5.1 is kind of old

use e.g. https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/   (at the bottom of the page)

The following steps worked fine for me on a new clean Ubuntu 17.04. install

#### **1. Get the .deb file**

https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/   (newest version is found at the total bottom of the page)

#### **2. Install gdebi**

`sudo apt-get install gdebi`

#### **3. Install unity using gdebi**

`sudo gdebi unity-editor_amd64-5.5.3xf1Linux.deb`

gdebi should now resolve the dependecies and show you which packages will be installed.

-> type 'y' + ENTER to install

"Unpacking unity-editor ()" can take a couple of minutes to finish so just be patient.

#### **4. start Unity3d**

Since most Desktops (I don't know which you are using) have a search function just search for "Unity". It should appear like here
[image]

#### **5. LogIn**

After the splash appears
 [image]

You will be asked to LogIn with you account data or to create one.
 [image]

And respond the following question with I aggree ;)
 [image]

#### **6. fix License-Error**

It might happen (for me it did) that there is an Licence-Error coming up.
 Here click on "Re-Activate" on the right
 [image]

And .. you will be asked once again to agrree
 [image]

After this you have to choose your License Type (For example personal ;) )
 [image]

And (though we said personal) responde the following (e.g. like this)
 [image]
 (Please be honest with this because developers of software also have to live from something ;) )

After finishing this step you should see this screen
 [image]

#### **7. Use Unity**

Create a new Project according to your needs and open it up.
 [image]

DONE :) You now should be able to use Unity on Ubuntu.

Comment: see updates to question

Comment: added a Step-by-Step that worked fine for me on a fresh and clean Ubuntu 17.04. Install